# Compile all handlebars files in a directory individually using grunt

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, browserify

I'd like to compile all my handlebars files in a directory to individual files, without explicitly specifying each file.

I essentially want the same functionality provided by glob_to_multiple in grunt-contrib-coffee.

Does anyone know of anything that can help me with this?

I was planning on using something like grunt-handlebarsify, but don't see that functionality offered.

The reason to do this is that I'd like to require my handlebars templates in my backbone views using browserify. So if anyone knows an alternative solution for this I'm all ears.

Thanks